# class variable compared to @Binding struct variable

Tags: swiftui

Is there any reason I should not use a class instance rather than using a struct instance and @Binding?
I am using two instances of a class Cat (sire and dam) to hold my data, and displaying them as a view.

```
ColourMenuView(cat: sire)
```

```
class Cat {
  init(sex: Sex = .male) {
    self.sex = sex
  }
...
}
```

and

```
struct ColourMenuView: View {
  var cat: Cat
  @State var colour = CatColour.black
    
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text("Colour:")
        .contextMenu {
          ForEach(CatColour.all, id: \.self) {i in
            Button(i.rawValue) { colour = i }
          }
        }
      Text(colour.rawValue)
    }
    .onChange(of: colour) { value in
      cat.colour = value
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to this method? Or should I make Cat a struct, and go

```
@Binding var cat
```

Comment: `@Binding` is generally used when you need to communicate state back up to a parent. It also tells the child and parent view to update when there's a state change. Generally, you want to keep as much of your state in value types as possible in SwiftUI -- it'll make your life much easier. In this case, it's not really clear what you're trying to do or when things update, so besides the above, it's hard to give a concrete recommendation. It does sound like you may want to go through the Apple or Hacking With Swift SwiftUI tutorials to get some of the fundamental concepts a little more concrete.

Comment: I am trying to create aa App to calculate what coat colours, and the probability of those coat colours occurring in the litter from a sire and dam of known colours. So I need to be able to store information about the coat colours and modifiers for both the sire and dam.I use these to generate potential colours of the kittens. This ColourMenuView is to collect the basic colour of the sire/dam. I am used to using classes to model my data, and wonder why I should use a reference to a struct, when a class is always referred to by reference.

Comment: Value types are preferred because SwiftUI's system of calculating changes via `@State`, `@Binding`, or `@Published` relies on a value types to work effectively.

Comment: Thanks. Had a good read of it and decided to use @EnvironmentObject